# Nothing happens when I try to import a project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, import, android-studio-2.0

There is my problem: I tried to import Google Maps API samples in android studio. But when I select directory in "Import project"s menu, nothing happens. There are no errors, just silence. Same situation when I try to import any google sample or opensource project.
I have Android Studio 2.1.2

**UPDATE:**

> Unable to save '/home/antonid/Android_Projects/android-ActionBarCompat-ShareActionProvider/local.properties'/home/antonid/Android_Projects/android-ActionBarCompat-ShareActionProvider/local.properties (Permission denied)'

Comment: what do you mean by nothing happens?

Comment: Can you tell system specs of your PC/Mac ?

Comment: I mean just NOTHING :)

Comment: Can I see a screenshot? That can help to see if you are looking at the right view in Project panel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**My solution:** I have allowed all to write down files in a project directory, using`chmod -R 777 project_dir`

Comment: That helped me as well. I've tried to import build.gradle from an android project created from ionic 2.

Answer (score 2):

Try this go to `File->Close Project` and instead using `Open an Existing Android Studio Project` use `Import Project (Eclipse ADT,Gradle,etc.)`.

Comment: I use Import Project

Comment: try to import a sample ,from `New->Import Sample` it's the simplest why to see if the problem is in your side or no

Answer (score 1):

For me, *sudo* needs to be prepended too:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /<path of the project>/android
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes when there is something wrong with your Gradle. Try Build >  Clean Project and then rebuild your project.